# JFrame, show image

Tags: java, jframe

I'm creating Jfreame application and i have a problem. I want to create event that's showing image. I have tried some of the ways, but it wont working.
How solve it?

```
private void openMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = f.getName();
    String filePath = f.getPath();

    String mimetype= new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
    String type = mimetype.split("/")[0];
    if(type.equals("image")){

        JPanel imageP = new JPanel();
        imageP.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filePath));
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(image1);
    add(label1);
    }        
    else{ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's NOT an image");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain your question a little more.

Comment: So, you have an JPanel for an image and an image, but don't do anything with that?

Comment: How display image of filePath on JFrame?

Comment: Class.getResource *does not* take a file name as an argument.  Change new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filePath)) to `new ImageIcon(image)`.